CycloneDDS and ROS2 Launch File

I have this very specific network setup for my robotic platforms:

Platform 1: RaspberryPi4, Ubuntu, Docker container with ROS2-humble over Ubuntu, access to Wlan0 and Eth0 (shared with P2)
Platform 2: RaspberryPi4, Raspbian, Docker container with ROS2-humble over Ubuntu, access to Eth0 (shared with P1)

The system is running with a CycloneDDS setup:

RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_cyclonedds_cpp 
CYCLONEDDS_URI=cyclonedds_P[*].xml

To startup the discovery, a ros2 daemon start is executed on both platforms. I'm trying to execute a launchfile on P1. 
In the case that P2 is not connected (i.e., Eth0 is down), I can launch some ROS2 nodes on P1, without any issue.
However, if P2 is connected, the launchfile fails, with some nodes showing this error:

python3: ./src/core/ddsi/src/ddsi_wraddrset.c:490: wras_cover_locatorset: Assertion `cover_get (cov, rdidx, lidx) == 0xff' failed.

Launching a single node will not generate this error. Launching a second node will make the first to abort generating this exact error.
I am attaching the setups for the two platforms:
cyclonedds_P1.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<CycloneDDS xmlns="https://cdds.io/config" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://cdds.io/config https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eclipse-cyclonedds/cyclonedds/master/etc/cyclonedds.xsd">
    <Domain Id="any">
        <General>
            <Interfaces>
                <NetworkInterface name="wlan0" priority="1"/>
                <NetworkInterface name="eth0"  priority="0" presence_required="false"/>
            </Interfaces>
            <MaxMessageSize>65500B</MaxMessageSize>
            <DontRoute>true</DontRoute>
            <RedundantNetworking>true</RedundantNetworking>
        </General>
        <Tracing><Verbosity>finest</Verbosity></Tracing>
    </Domain>
</CycloneDDS>

cyclonedds_P2.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<CycloneDDS xmlns="https://cdds.io/config" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://cdds.io/config https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eclipse-cyclonedds/cyclonedds/master/etc/cyclonedds.xsd">
    <Domain Id="any">
        <General>
            <Interfaces>
                <NetworkInterface name="eth0" priority="0"/>
            </Interfaces>
            <MaxMessageSize>65500B</MaxMessageSize>
            <DontRoute>true</DontRoute>
        </General>
    </Domain>
</CycloneDDS>

Another step of my testing made me add some internal network information for both platforms:

<NetworkInterface name="docker0" priority="2"/>

but, probably because this networks holds no carrier, nothing has changed.
Specifing the IPv4 address for each network is also not influencing the behavior.
After turning off P2, the error was still showing up in P1 launchfile execution. After resetting the system or stopping the ROS2 daemon on P1, the error was gone.
Does anyone have faced similar issues?
